# getExtras().getParcelableArrayList vs getParcelableArrayExtra

Tags: java, android

I'm new with android and my question is really simple.
What's the diffrence between `getExtras().getParcelableArrayList` and `getParcelableArrayExtra` ?

Comment: `getExtras()` give you bundle and you call `getParcelableArrayList` on the same while you call `getParcelableArrayExtra` on intent. you might want to take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243798/advantages-of-using-bundle-instead-of-direct-intent-putextra-in-android

Comment: So basically it depends on the method used when the extra was passed to the intent object.
thanks :)