# How to develop a basic online ordering app?

Tags: android

I need a small clarity regarding developing an android app. Basically the idea is to build an app where the user can select the items(eg.books), after selecting, he will be taken to next activity where he can choose the number of items(say 2). After selecting he will be taken to another activity where he is given option to pay online. After the payment, the seller(that is me) should generate a bill containing the details provided by the user.

So my doubt is, how to know what items has he selected and the details(how do I receive that info) he had entered and how do I generate a bill back to him?

Please help me with this.
I just need an idea of how to implement it.

Thank you!

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819427/7557205) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243798/advantages-of-using-bundle-instead-of-direct-intent-putextra-in-android) will also help

Answer (score 0):

Create a server application with a database to store the details of customer purchase. Server application cold be a web application and you can connect your application with android app by using web services or http connection. For any temporary storage in app,use sqlite database for android.